# Forgot Bitlocker Key After Dell BIOS Factory Reset

Tags: bitlocker

I forgot my Bitlocker key after a factory reset of the BIOS of my Dell Laptop (Dell XPS).

I cannot seem to find the key, how do I unlock my computer?

Answer (score 1):

While usually either the Bitlocker Key or the Password (not PIN) is required for  unlocking the encrypted drive, it is also permissible to revert all changes which led to the prompt of a Bitlocker event.

In this scenario of a Dell factory reset this is disabling TPM. Please press F12 upon boot up to enter the BIOS menu, re-enable TPM, which is deactivated in the default settings.

The Bitlocker screen should now disappear. This occured to me on a Dell  XPS 13 7390.